# SWT Spinner - Disabling Keyboard Editing

Tags: java, swt, spinner

On SWT spinner (or maybe some other similar SWT widget), how can I force the user to use the UI buttons instead of edit the text from the keyboard. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SWT.READ_ONLY` will prevent the user from entering values. To disable arrow keys as well, you can do something like this:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    Spinner spinner = new Spinner(shell, SWT.READ_ONLY);
    spinner.addListener(SWT.Verify, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event e)
        {
            if(e.keyCode == SWT.ARROW_UP || e.keyCode == SWT.ARROW_DOWN)
            {
                e.doit = false;
            }
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.setSize(100, shell.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT).y);
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!shell.getDisplay().readAndDispatch())
            shell.getDisplay().sleep();
    }
}
```

This will make sure that the only way to change the `Spinner` value is using the buttons.

Comment: Thanks. but I still have a small problem, if I push the arrow buttons the digit inside the spiner is highlighted. Its not just inside the spinner, every label that includes text in my UI can be highlighted with the mouse. Is it possible to make the text act like an image? that means, to disable the option to highlight it or put the writing cursor in it

Comment: @user1640382 I'm fairly sure that's not possible. You might be better off creating a custom widget with a `Text` and two `Button`s. Then you can make it look and feel the way you want it to.